# Excel, Vba ,cells value, How to transform code so it is as in screenshot?

Tags: excel, vba

some time ago I started writing macro that will do same as in screenshot([good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZA2Il.png)) , but so far it prints as in this screenshot([bad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6Jb7.png)). I've been battling with it for a long time and don't know what to do, after ruuning the macro it seems that something is wrong with the for loop(1 on this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6Jb7.png)),as after going through if it stays there (the komz>kom). Also where there is 2 on the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6Jb7.png) there should be diffrence ( komz = komz - kom) and date from above

Code before:

```
Sub testro()
Const cSheet As String = "Procenty"
    Const cRange As String = "A2:D71"
    Const cel As Long = 4
    Const cCol As Variant = "A"


    Dim vntS As Variant
    Dim vntT As Variant
    Dim i As Long, r As Long
    Dim emptyRow As Long

    Dim kom As Double, komz As Double, kredyt As Double
    Dim roz As Double, komr As Double, komn As Double
    Dim dz As Date, dw As Date

    vntS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet).Range(cRange).Value
    ReDim vntT(1 To 3 * UBound(vntS), 1 To cel + 1)
    kredyt = 0

    r = 1

    For i = 1 To UBound(vntS)

        dz = vntS(i, 1)
        komz = vntS(i, 2)
        dw = vntS(i, 3)
        kom = vntS(i, 4)



       If komz > kom Then


vntT(r, 1) = dz
vntT(r, 2) = komz 'debt
vntT(r, 3) = dw
vntT(r, 4) = kom 'payment
vntT(r, 5) = " komz>kom"

r = r + 1

komz = komz - kom

    vntT(r, 1) = dz
    vntT(r, 2) = komz ' Debt
    vntT(r, 3) = dw
    vntT(r, 4) = kom  '  payment
    vntT(r, 5) = " .. komz > kom"



ElseIf komz < kom Then

    komn = kom - komz

    vntT(r, 1) = dz
vntT(r, 2) = komz
vntT(r, 3) = dw
vntT(r, 4) = kom
vntT(r, 5) = " .. A"

r = r + 1

    vntT(r, 3) = dw
    vntT(r, 4) = komn  ' Overpaid
    vntT(r, 5) = " .. komz < kom"

    r = r + 1

ElseIf komz = kom Then
    vntT(r, 1) = dz
    vntT(r, 2) = komz  ' debt
    vntT(r, 3) = dw
    vntT(r, 4) = kom   ' payment
    vntT(r, 5) = " .. komz = kom"

    r = r + 1

End If


    Next

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet)
        emptyRow = .Columns(cCol).Find("*", , xlFormulas, xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Row + 1
        .Cells(emptyRow, cCol).Resize(UBound(vntT), UBound(vntT, 2)) = vntT
        .Cells(emptyRow, cCol) = kredyt
    End With
End Sub
```

EDIT1: Now it prints like this on the [picture][now] I marked what needs to be where, and also it should like "go through" the if statements to determine what needs to be done

EDIT2: [Now][nown] it prints almost the same as before,what I need to do is: hwen the value from 2nd column is not payed off by one from 4th then from the row the value to be payed off(1 on [shot][nown] actually the rest of it is put under with its date(2 on the [shot][nown]) and then in the same row the payment after is added,it should work until the value is completely payed off

Code after:

```
Sub testro()
Const cSheet As String = "Procenty"
    Const cRange As String = "A2:D71"
    Const cel As Long = 4
    Const cCol As Variant = "A"


    Dim vntS As Variant
    Dim vntT As Variant
    Dim i As Long, r As Long
    Dim emptyRow As Long

    Dim kom As Double, komz As Double, kredyt As Double
    Dim roz As Double, komr As Double, komn As Double
    Dim dz As Date, dw As Date

    vntS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet).Range(cRange).Value
    ReDim vntT(1 To 3 * UBound(vntS), 1 To cel + 1)
    kredyt = 0

    r = 1

    For i = 1 To UBound(vntS)

        dz = vntS(i, 1)
        komz = vntS(i, 2)
        dw = vntS(i, 3)
        kom = vntS(i, 4)

 If komz > kom Then

If CStr(vntT(r, 1)) = "" Then 'because of this if-statement, it will not overwrite previous values
   vntT(r, 1) = dz
   vntT(r, 2) = komz 'debt
End If
vntT(r, 3) = dw
vntT(r, 4) = kom 'payment
vntT(r, 5) = " komz>kom"

r = r + 1
ElseIf komz < kom Then

    komn = kom - komz

    vntT(r, 1) = dz
vntT(r, 2) = komz
vntT(r, 3) = dw
vntT(r, 4) = kom
vntT(r, 5) = " .. A"

r = r + 1

    vntT(r, 3) = dw
    vntT(r, 4) = komn  ' Overpaid
    vntT(r, 5) = " .. komz < kom"

    r = r + 1

ElseIf komz = kom Then
    vntT(r, 1) = dz
    vntT(r, 2) = komz  ' debt
    vntT(r, 3) = dw
    vntT(r, 4) = kom   ' payment
    vntT(r, 5) = " .. komz = kom"

    r = r + 1

End If


    Next

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet)
        emptyRow = .Columns(cCol).Find("*", , xlFormulas, xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Row + 1
        .Cells(emptyRow, cCol).Resize(UBound(vntT), UBound(vntT, 2)) = vntT
        .Cells(emptyRow, cCol) = kredyt
    End With
End Sub
```

EDIT3:

Images deleted links in comment below(exceeded limit)
 [Original values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcIby.png) [Values now][1] values underlined by red are like "ate" while they should be in same rows as the blue ones

EDIT4: 
Here's [data][2] (can't put it in text here)

EDIT5: Google drive link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1k6FAibzbH3GbDVVst_P1Ln0IkolI-k3Y  (folder)
https://drive.google.com/open?id=19u8D0knPAyZwuxhzfFZo8VYeSeBXoTT6  (file)
 I had to delete some images (exceeded limit again,too low reputation)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ni9e.png

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qw92U.png

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put `r = r + 1` after

```
komz = komz - kom

    vntT(r, 1) = dz
    vntT(r, 2) = komz ' Debt
    vntT(r, 3) = dw
    vntT(r, 4) = kom  '  payment
    vntT(r, 5) = " .. komz > kom"
```

So it overwrites this bit in the next loop.

EDIT: So hopefully I understand it now and this is what you need:
I think that it's correct that you overwrite your row, but it only needs to overwrite the last three columns. Therefore I think that in this particular case, you need to check if there is already a value in the array on that position, so you don't overwrite it:

```
 If komz > kom Then

If cstr(vntT(r,1)) = "" then 'because of this if-statement, it will not overwrite previous values
   vntT(r, 1) = dz
   vntT(r, 2) = komz 'debt
end if
vntT(r, 3) = dw
vntT(r, 4) = kom 'payment
vntT(r, 5) = " komz>kom"

r = r + 1
```

EDIT  (again): I played around with your data and maybe this is what you need?:

```
    If komz > kom Then
        If CStr(vntT(r, 1)) = "" Then 'because of this if-statement, it will not overwrite previous values
            vntT(r, 1) = dz
            vntT(r, 2) = komz 'debt
        End If
        vntT(r, 3) = dw
        vntT(r, 4) = kom 'payment
        vntT(r, 5) = " komz>kom"

        r = r + 1
        vntT(r, 1) = dz
        vntT(r, 2) = komz - kom
        vntS(i + 1, 2) = komz - kom
    ElseIf komz < kom Then
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to handle the payments, but it comes closest to your original sample where everything worked well.

Comment: Well it's still not good,not what I wanted in EDIT1 wrote you can see how it is now and I wrote how it should be

Comment: Look at the other if-statement where it goes correct. There you only fill in 'vntT` 3 to 5. Here you fill in 1 to 5 and you also fill in `komz` in column 2, but that needs to be in column 4 I think, because that's the variable you changed.

Comment: Well in column 4 should be another value not the one changed but like next payment and this line should also go through the ifs to determine what should be done. It should look like in the good tag above, where I did it manually

Comment: Ok, so you actually need a bit of the row to be overwritten, but just not the first two cells?

Comment: Well I think that main problem with this is that I just can't really explain it :( ... It should go just as in the screeshot tagged good, I thought that adding value like balance and maybe until loop should do the trick but don't know how to do this actually....

Comment: I will change my answer for what I think you mean, hopefully I understand it correctly :)

Comment: Well it's almost the same as before in EDIT2 I explained I think clear what I want to do with this

Comment: Can you update your code what you use for the latest edit?

Comment: the bit with `komz = komz - kom` and the bit after it is gone now. Why is that? I think you should put that back.

Comment: Now it's gone in good direction :)  but it's not solved already :(. You see now it's printing good value BUT this value should also be checked by ifs in macro so for e.g in komz>kom after it's subtracted the new kom should also be checked by all ifs.Also this new macro kind of ate some values (e.g in EDIT3) while it should just assign next komz its value from kom (when previous komz is payed off)

Comment: Could you help me ?
I do not know what to do now with it and the problem is not solved already

Comment: Can you post the data? Because I think the only way to get it right is to loop through the code to see what happens and where you want it to be different.

Comment: It's in EDIT4 section now

Comment: Okay now I posted some examplary data in EDIT5 section (links to google drive)

Comment: Hi I'm sorry that I took some time to answer, had some personal issues, but maybe my last edit will help.